# Using GregorianCalendar - Error

Tags: java

What is wrong with this code?

```
GregorianCalendar today = new GregorianCalendar();
GregorianCalendar hundredDays = today.add(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 100);
```

It always returns "incompatible types"

```
required: GregorianCalendar
found: void
```

Comment: Did you read the doc of `GregorianCalendar`?

Comment: Yes I just did. Sorry I'm new to java, 2 days in so I'm not familiar with everything just yet

Answer (score 0):

Below is the signature of add

```
void java.util.GregorianCalendar.add(int field, int amount)
```

It doesn't return anything. So when you try to assign void to GregorianCalendar, you will get a compilation error

Answer (score 0):

The [`add` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#add-int-int-) doesn't return a new `GregorianCalendar`; it modifies the existing one.  It returns `void`.  Try

```
today.add(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 100);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now it makes sense! Sorry I'm 2 days into java